# Access SUMMARIZECOLUMNS FILTER Min value

Tags: dax

```
EVALUATE
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
      'DimDate'[Year],
      'DimDate'[Month_Of_Year],
      FILTER('DimDate', 'DimDate'[Year] = 2016 ),
      "MyMeasure", 'FactTable'[MyMeasure],
    )
```

How can my measure `MyMeasure` access the mimimum date from the filtered DimDate table to get the value `1-Jan-2016`?

I've tried:

`MyMeasure:=CALCULATE( MIN( DimDate[Actual_Date] ), ALL( DimDate[Actual_Date] ) )`

but it returns the date from each summarized row.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your measure, the `ALL` function is only removing the filter context for the column `DimDate[Actual_Date]`, but still keeping the `[Year]` and `[Month_Of_Year]` context.

If you write `ALL(DimDate)`, that should remove all filters from the table, but since you mentioned you want the minimum date from the *filtered* table, you may want to use `ALLSELECTED(DimDate)` instead. That will preserve any filtering based on things like slicers.